# Spring Cloud Eureka - How to mock RestTemplate in order to avoid request to a second service

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am triing to write an integration test for one of my microservice that before saving the object in the database, makes a call to another microservice in order to perform some validation.

Since the second microservice is not running, I want to mock the request to the external service but the test is failing with an error:

```
Condition failed with Exception:

mockServer.verify()
|          |
|          java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s).
|          0 request(s) executed.
|           
|           at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.verify(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:159)
|           at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer.verify(MockRestServiceServer.java:116)
```

Below is the Test logic:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PropertyApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = ["eureka.client.enabled:false"])
class TestPropertyListingServiceDemo extends IntegrationTestsSetup {
@Autowired
private PropertyListingService listingService
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate

private static MockRestServiceServer mockServer


def setup() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate)
}


def "test: save listing for in-existent User"() {

    setup: "building listing with invalid user id"
    def listing = generatePropertyListing()

    mockServer.expect(once(), requestTo("http://user-service/rest/users/exists/trackingId=" + listing.getUserTID()))
            .andExpect(method(GET))
            .andRespond(withStatus(NOT_FOUND).body("No such user."))


    when: "saving listing"
    listingService.save(listing)

    then: "exception is thrown"
    mockServer.verify() // <------------- here I am getting the error

    BizItemBusinessValidationException e = thrown()
    e.getMessage() == "Listing could not be saved. User not found."
}
```

}

Service I am testing with the request I am triing to mock:

```
@Service
public class PropertyListingService {
private BizItemService itemService;
private PropertyService propertyService;
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public PropertyListingService(BizItemService itemService,PropertyService propertyService, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.propertyService = propertyService;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    this.itemService=itemService;
}


public PropertyListing save(PropertyListing listing) {

    if (listing == null) {
        throw new BizItemBusinessValidationException("Listing could not be saved. Invalid Listing.");
    }

    if (propertyService.findByTrackingId(listing.getPropertyTID()) == null) {
        throw new BizItemBusinessValidationException("Listing could not be saved. Property not found.");
    }

    if (userExists(listing.getUserTID())) {
        throw new BizItemBusinessValidationException("Listing Could not be saved. User not found, UserTID = " + listing.getUserTID());
    }

    return (PropertyListing) itemService.save(listing);
}


/**------------------------------------------------------------
 * THIS IS THE CALL TO EXTERNAL SERVICE I AM TRYING TO MOCK
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private boolean userExists(String userTID) {
    URI uri = URI.create("http://user-service/rest/users/exists/trackingId=" + userTID);
    ResponseEntity response = (ResponseEntity) restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Object.class);

    return response != null && response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

}

RestTemplate configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have your test create a mock rest template bean?

Answer (score 1):

As @spencergibb rightly suggested you could mock your restTemplate as part of your test configs.

Second option,you could try using MockRestServiceServer.

Check this below link. See if it helps your case.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template

Answer (score 0):

To get my tests executed I did the following steps:

1.Disabled eureka client

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PropertyApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["eureka.client.enabled:false"])
```

1.Disabled eureka client 
Mocked RestTemplate as @spancergibb suggested and Injected my service with Autowire (as a regular spring bean)

```
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplateMock

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private PropertyListingService listingService
```

3. Invoked the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) before mocking RestTemplate method.

   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
   URI uri = URI.create(servicesConfig.getUsersServiceURI() + "/rest/users/exists/trackingId=" + userTID)

Mockito.when(restTemplateMock.getForEntity(uri, 
ResponseEntity.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity)

Below is my full test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PropertyApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["eureka.client.enabled:false"])
class TestPropertyListingService extends IntegrationTestsSetup {


    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplateMock

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private PropertyListingService listingService

    @Autowired
    private PropertyService propertyService

    static boolean testsSetupExecuted
    static Property dbProperty

    def setup() {
        if (!testsSetupExecuted) {
            schemaService.initSchema()
            purgeCollection(PropertyListing.simpleName)
            dbProperty = propertyService.save(generateProperty())
            testsSetupExecuted = true
        }
    }


    def "test: save listing for in-existent User"() {
        setup:
        def listing = generatePropertyListing()
        listing.setPropertyTID(dbProperty.getTrackingId())
        mockUserRestCall(listing.userTID, new ResponseEntity("Mocking: User not found", NOT_FOUND))

        when: "saving listing"
        listingService.save(listing)

        then: "exception is thrown"
        BizItemBusinessValidationException e = thrown()
        e.getMessage() == "Listing could not be saved. User not found, UserTID = ${listing.userTID}"
    }

    def "test: save listing with past checkin/checkout date"() {
        setup:
        def listing = generatePropertyListing()
        listing.setPropertyTID(dbProperty.getTrackingId())
        mockUserRestCall(listing.userTID, new ResponseEntity("Mocked response", OK));

        when: "saving with past dates"
        listing.setCheckInDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000))
        listing.setCheckOutDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000))
        listingService.save(listing)

        then: "exception is thrown"
        BizItemSchemaValidationException e = thrown()
        e.getMessage().startsWith('[PropertyListing] validation failed [[Invalid future date for [CheckIn Date] =')
        e.getMessage().contains('Invalid future date for [CheckOut Date] =')
    }



    def mockUserRestCall(String userTID, ResponseEntity responseEntity) {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        URI uri = URI.create(servicesConfig.getUsersServiceURI() + "/rest/users/exists/trackingId=" + userTID)
        Mockito.when(restTemplateMock.getForEntity(uri, ResponseEntity.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity)
    }
}
```